# How to validate a laminas form collection both on the parent form as well as on the coresponding collection's fieldset elements?

Tags: laminas

I have a form containing a collection *financingSources* and the corresponding child fieldset *FinancingSourceFieldset* containing an input *share*. The fieldsets `getInputFilterSpeicfication()` method returns the input filter specification and works perfectly fine. But I also want to do the following validation: The *shares* of all *financingSources* should sum up to 100%. For that I have specified an input *financingSources* in the parent form's `getInputFilterSpecification()` with a callback validator which assumes this task.

But Laminas won't add the `InputFilterSpecification` of the child fieldset anymore, if there is already an input specified in the parent form's InputFilterSpecification.

What can I do to be able to validate **both** the share sum and the child fieldset's elements?